# Commenting Array values instead of Removing them

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just out of curiosity, Is there any difference in terms of Performance between Removing a value from the Array and Just commenting it instead of removing it from the Array.

We have an array `let arr = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4}]` and have to remove the last value. instead of using array methods, we either remove the value manually or comment it.

We have two Arrays i.e, `let arr1 = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]` and

```
    let arr2 = [
    {a:1},
    {b:2},
    {c:3},
    // {d:4}
    ]
```

Here in arr1 the last value is removed from the code and in arr2 the value is commented. Functionality wise the two arrays will give 3 as their length, is there any performance issue if we have commented code inside the array or any issue in general?

Comment: Comments are completely ignored when code is executed; it's as if the code isn't there at all.

Comment: except size of source file (for example if includes too many comments) which can also be neglisible, there is no performance problem with simply commenting out code instead of removing it completely

Comment: If you're going to minify the code before putting it in production, the comment is removed anyway. There are no measurable performance costs when commenting a single line from a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comments are scanned over like whitespace so they wont be processed. However if you are looking at work done too then it actually does affect performance with respect to time

Comment: The difference can be counted in nanoseconds, probably nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

No, commented out code is never executed and completely ignored so no performance issue really other than the size of your file would be a bit larger.